# i did configuration in context but it creates new column ef core migration?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a table called A , B , and AB.

```
public class A {
  public int Id {get;set;}
...
}


public class B {
  public int Id {get;set;}
...
}

public class AB {
  public int AId {get;set;}
  public int BId {get;set;}

public A A {get;set;}
public B B {get;set;}


}
```

In context on OnModelCreating method I write

```
            //modelBuilder.Entity<AB>().HasKey(x => new { x.AId, x.BId});
            //modelBuilder.Entity<AB>().HasOne(x => x.A);
            //modelBuilder.Entity<AB>().HasOne(x => x.B);
```

when i add migration it creates new columns called AId1, BId1 .

Answer (score 0):

You need to complete your relationship definition: set the other-end cardinality, and set your foreign key fields (otherwise it creates one for you, which is why you see the new columns being created).

For example, if it's a one-to-many relationship, something like:

```
public class A {
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public ICollection<AB> ABs { get; set; }
  // ...
}

//...
modelBuilder.Entity<AB>().HasOne(x => x.A).WithMany(x => x.ABs).HasForeignKey(x => x.AId);
```

Same with `B`

PS: the `ICollection` property wouldn't be strictly necessary, but it's usually a nice-to-have... if you want to do it without it, this should work:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AB>().HasOne(x => x.A).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.AId);
```

You can see how other type of relationships are defined in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships